# Is there a way to highlight spellcheck collation in Solr?

Tags: solr, websolr

Using Solr:

- I was able to highlight matched terms in a query
- I was able to implement the spellcheck component: Did you mean: `collation`?

Is it possible to highlight the **corrected/suggested** word in the spellcheck?
example: https://www.google.com/search?q=I+have+fevert
it returns: I have **fever**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr itself doesn't support this. It is something you can handle in the client.